# Opencart Filters add onclick event to replace the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

I would like to add an onclick event to the Opencart filters to replace the submit button which is hidden off the page..  I am presuming that this should be done with javascript/jquery, but implementation is a little beyond me, can you help?

**PHP:**

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
 <div class="box-content">
  <ul class="box-filter">
   <?php foreach ($filter_groups as $filter_group) { ?>
   <li><span id="filter-group<?php echo $filter_group['filter_group_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter_group['name']; ?></span>
    <ul>
     <?php foreach ($filter_group['filter'] as $filter) { ?>
     <?php if (in_array($filter['filter_id'], $filter_category)) { ?>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
      <label for="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
     </li>
     <?php } else { ?>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>" />
      <label for="filter<?php echo $filter['filter_id']; ?>"><?php echo $filter['name']; ?></label>
     </li>
     <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <a id="button-filter" class="button"><?php echo $button_filter; ?></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**HTML OUTPUT:**

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-heading">Refine Search</div>
 <div class="box-content">
  <ul class="box-filter">
   <li><span id="filter-group2">Colour</span>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" value="33" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter33">
     <label for="filter33">Black</label>
    </li>
    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" value="35" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter35">
     <label for="filter35">Blue</label>
    </li>
    <li><span id="filter-group4">Scent Name</span>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="64" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter64">
      <label for="filter64">Almond</label>
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="65" class="click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter" id="filter65">
      <label for="filter65">Coconut</label>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <a id="button-filter" class="button">Refine Search</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-filter').bind('click', function() {
    filter = [];

    $('.box-filter input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked').each(function(element) {
        filter.push(this.value);
    });

    location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
});
//--></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this (instead of the current script):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the "submit" button
    $('#button-filter').hide();

    // bind onChange event to the checkboxes
    $('.click_checkbox_manufacturers-filter').live('change', function() {
        filter = [];

        $('.box-filter input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked').each(function(element) {
            filter.push(this.value);
        });

        window.location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Here is [link to my JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LaaLS/) of the very same JS code, which, surprisingly is **working**. The only issue may be with redirect... I edited the redirect code above so it should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help Shadyx, but it don't work.. hides the button though!

Comment: @Stuart I do not see a reason why it shouldn't work now. Do You get some JS error (e.g. in console in Firebug)? Try add `document.` before the `location` at the end of script...

Comment: @Stuart Without a clarification *why it does not work* or without an error message I cannot help You...

Comment: Turns out it didn;t like the hyphen in the input box class? fixed, working, sound, thank you so very very much.. x

Comment: @doug65536 Though this is true, even the latest OpenCart (to date) 1.5.6 uses jQuery 1.7.1 and `live()` was deprecated just one minor version (1.7.0) before. So this is not a big deal until jQuery >1.9.0 is used in OpenCart...

Answer (score 1):

For version 2 change the JavaScript in the filter.tpl file (from catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/module/filter.tpl - change 'default' to your theme name if necessary) to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button-filter').hide();

        $('input[name^=\'filter\']').on('change', function() {
           filter = [];

            $('input[name^=\'filter\']:checked').each(function(element) {
               filter.push(this.value);
        });

        location = '<?php echo $action; ?>&filter=' + filter.join(',');
     });
});
</script>
```

Tested in OC 2.3.0.2.